# Issues with geting results from filter inside filters

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Guys i'm trying to filter some info from this array, a piece of it:

```
{
    "entry": [
        {
            "ent_seq": 1000090,
            "k_ele": [
                {
                    "keb": "○"
                },
                {
                    "keb": "〇"
                }
            ],
            "r_ele": {
                "reb": "まる"
            },
            "sense": [
                {
                    "pos": "&n;",
                    "xref": "〇〇・まるまる・1",
                    "gloss": "symbol used as a placeholder (either because a number of other words could be used in that position, or because of censorship)"
                },
                {
                    "pos": "&n;",
                    "xref": "句点",
                    "gloss": [
                        "period",
                        "full stop"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "pos": "&n;",
                    "xref": "半濁点",
                    "gloss": [
                        "maru mark",
                        "semivoiced sound",
                        "p-sound"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
```

Here we have the 'sense' item, where he can be an array or not, and inside of it the 'gloss' item, an array or not as well.
To do the main search, im doing this:

```
export const mainSearch = async (req, res) => {

var filterData2 = teste.entry.filter(x => {
   
    if ('sense' in x && Array.isArray(x['sense'])) {
        let result = x.sense.filter(sense_item => {
            if (Array.isArray(x.sense['gloss'])) {

                let result2 = sense_item.gloss.includes(req.params.id) 

            } else if (x.sense.gloss === req.params.id) return x
        })        
    }
    if(result) return x
}

)
if (filterData2) {
    console.log(filterData2)
    // res.json(filterData2)
}
```

Where i receive the search item from req.params.id, and i already tried dozens of things, im really stucked here, for the result right now i'm getting an empty array

The aim is if i get a true response for the search, to let the 'first filter' perceive it and go checking the rest.

For the 'k_ele' and 'r_ele' my code works fine too, a piece of it:

```
 if ('k_ele' in x && Array.isArray(x['k_ele'])) {
         let result = x.k_ele.some(el =>
             el.keb.includes(req.params.id)
         )
         if (result) return x
     } else
         if ('k_ele' in x && x.k_ele.keb === req.params.id) return x
```

Comment: The `filter` method requires you to return a value, which is either truthy or falsy. At the moment you return neither. That will result in an empty array.

Comment: Just a side suggestion, don't use `x` for variable naming. Be more careful on variable naming which come in handy when you're in complicated projects.

Comment: Could you explain what the final result should be, preferably with a code example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The person that posted an answer earlier gave me some clues, but he deleted it.

About the answer, the initial state of the logic was already too messy, and it was unable to return the true or false that the first 'filter' needed, that was the main problem.

So, i just started over focusing on the 'return' part and was there that things got better, anymore than that is just improvements to the code.

```
 if ('sense' in x && !Array.isArray(x['sense'])) {
        if (Array.isArray(x.sense['gloss'])) {
            return x.sense.gloss.some(el => typeof(el) == 'string' && el.includes(req.params.id))           
        } else return typeof(x.sense.gloss) == 'string' && x.sense.gloss.includes(req.params.id)
    } else if ('sense' in x && Array.isArray(x['sense'])) {
        return x.sense.some((sense_item) => {
            if (Array.isArray(sense_item['gloss'])) {
                return sense_item.gloss.some(el => typeof(el) == 'string' && el.includes(req.params.id)) 
            } else return typeof(sense_item.gloss) == 'string' && sense_item.gloss.includes(req.params.id)
        })       
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you change your strategy. If the data is hard to filter and loop through, then it might be a good idea to change the data to something that is easier to work with.

In the end you'd want to check if the `req.params.id` is found in any of the `gloss` arrays or strings. Therefor it might be a good idea to collect all items in the `gloss` items into a single array and check if the queried value is found in any of the strings.

```
const data = [ 
  "symbol used as a placeholder (either because a number of other words could be used in that position, or because of censorship)", 
  "period", 
  "full stop", 
  "maru mark", 
  "semivoiced sound", 
  "p-sound" 
]
```

With the data like the example above, you'd only have to evaluate if the string you're looking for is present in the array.

```
const isFound = data.includes(value)
```

```js
const teste={"entry":[{"ent_seq":1000090,"k_ele":[{"keb":"○"},{"keb":"〇"}],"r_ele":{"reb":"まる"},"sense":[{"pos":"&n;","xref":"〇〇・まるまる・1","gloss":"symbol used as a placeholder (either because a number of other words could be used in that position, or because of censorship)"},{"pos":"&n;","xref":"句点","gloss":["period","full stop"]},{"pos":"&n;","xref":"半濁点","gloss":["maru mark","semivoiced sound","p-sound"]}]}]};

// Example search request.
var req = {
  params: {
    id: 'full stop'
  }
}

/**
 * Check if the sense property is present and is an array.
 * Then return an array of all sense objects.
 */
const senseEntries = teste.entry
  .filter(entry => 'sense' in entry && Array.isArray(entry.sense))
  .flatMap(({
    sense
  }) => sense)

/**
 * Loop over the filtered sense objects and return
 * either the gloss array or the gloss string inside of an array.
 */
const glossEntries = senseEntries
  .flatMap(({
    gloss
  }) => Array.isArray(gloss) ? gloss : [gloss])
  
console.log(glossEntries);

/**
 * Now all gloss items are collected in a single array and we can check if the id is found in any of the gloss strings.
 */
const isFound = glossEntries.includes(req.params.id)
console.log(`${req.params.id} in gloss values?`, isFound);
```